# Styling radio buttons into a square

Tags: jquery, css

I was given a design with square radio buttons.

[image]

Is there a way to style radio buttons to look like this?

The only way, I think I could accomplish this is by using images, and swap the checked/checked state via an `$.on('click')` method.

Comment: You don't have to use images, you can use CSS, but that is the prefered way to go as radio buttons are generated by the browsers.

Comment: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/#pureCSS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need to style a radio button. Just use a div:

Example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLGf4/2/

html:

```
 <section>
    <header>
         <h1>Perfered Method of Contact</h1>

    </header>
    <div> <span>Choice 1</span>

        <div class="square-radio square-radio--clicked">
             <div class="square-radio--content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div> <span>Choice 2</span>

        <div class="square-radio">
            <div class="square-radio--content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.square-radio {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;

}
.square-radio--clicked .square-radio--content{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".square-radio", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("square-radio--clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: @RobM Updated to be exactly what you want.

Comment: These are not radio buttons... these are just large checkboxes created with css... A radio button is mutually exclusive in that only one per set can ever be selected.

Comment: @Phlume its easy to figure out how you would achieve that with this setup. I've done the heavy lifting for you already. All you have to do is iterate `".square-radio"` and uncheck all before you check the one that was clicked.  This gives you the most freedom in styling the buttons the way you want, while maintaining cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: wasn't my question. the OP asked for radio buttons.. these are not them. Just saying.

Comment: @agconti, you're right.  It is exactly what I'm looking for. As for Phlume's point, yes I was looking for radio buttons, but with your answer, I will be able to create the javascript to make the act as if they were.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes you can't replace the radio input by a div… so how styling a radio input into a square?

Comment: Changing the radio to a div for styling and emulating the functionality for the exclusiveness and their submission in forms via Javascript just for styling is backwards.

Answer (score 38):

This can be done quite easily with only CSS, no need for JS. The basic concept is to style an element that is a sibling of the input, creating a "fake" radio button:

```css
/* 
 * Hide the inputs. 
 */

input {
  display: none;
}


/*
 * Then, style the label so it looks like however you want.
 * Here's a quick rundown of how I did it here:
 */


/*
 * Some basic positioning styles, and we give it the pointer cursor to show 
 * that it's clickable
 */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*
 * With how I decided to build this, the position: relative is super important.
 * We're going to position a pseudo element within this element(As it is the containing box)
 */

label span {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 22px;
}


/* 
 * Because we're using pseudo elements, a content property is required to make them appear.
 */

label span:before,
label span:after {
  content: '';
}


/*
 * We are using the :before peudo elemnt as the actual button,
 * then we'll position the :after over it. You could also use a background-image,
 * font-icon, or really anything if you want different styles.
 * For the specific style we're going for, this approach is simply the easiest, but
 * once you understand the concept you can really do it however you like.
 */

label span:before {
  border: 1px solid #222021;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

label span:after {
  background: #222021;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  transition: 300ms;
  opacity: 0;
}

/*
 * This is the most important part of this whole file, if you understand what's happening here
 * you can really make this in so many different ways.
 * 
 * We start by selecting the input inside of the label, with "label input". From there we use the 
 * ":checked" selector to *only* select the input when it is checked. We then use the immediate sibling 
 * selector(+) to select the span, and then it's pseudo element :after(What we are using to mark the button)
 * Because we already styled the :after, all we have to do is set the opacity to 1, making it fade in.
 */
label input:checked+span:after {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* 
 * A little styling for the demo 
 */

body {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span>EMAIL</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span>PHONE</span>
</label>
```

Check the code comments for a more in-depth explanation, but here's the basics:

---

Start by creating a `<label>` as the wrapper. We use a label because events triggered on it will also be triggered on the associated input:

```
<label></label>
```

Add a input to it:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="demo">
</label>
```

Remember that radio buttons have to have the same name to be grouped. Now we throw a `<span>` after the input, so we have something to target in our CSS.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="demo">
    <span></span>
</label>
```

And the HTML is all set. Check the CSS for the explanation there, it'll be easier to understand.

Comment: Great job in actually answering the OP's question, good implementation as well, this should be the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the simplest I know of, a pure CSS solution requiring no labels or scripting. A couple of vendor prefixes are required for full compatibility:

```
input[type='radio'] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background: white;
  outline: 2px solid #333;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

input[type='radio']:checked {
  background: #333;
}
```

As noted above, the `box-sizing` and `appearance` properties should be vendor-prefixed:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work correctly with BootStrap

Comment: This solution is plain and simple!

Answer (score 5):

```css
input[type=radio] {
  padding: 0.5em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: 0.1em solid black;
  outline-offset: 0.1em;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<label for="radioA"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="A"/> A</label><br>
<label for="radioB"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="B"/> B</label><br>
<label for="radioC"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="C"/> C</label><br>
<label for="radioD"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="D"/> D</label>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML:

```
<label class="active">
    Email
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="n1" value="email" checked />
</label>
<label>
    Phone
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="n1" value="phone" />
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
  width: 125px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
label input {
  display: none;
}
label span {
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
label.active span:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background: black;
}
```

JS (requires jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle where you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wqdHE/2/

Answer (score 0):

While searching for implementing squared radio buttons in context of Bootstrap I ended up finding this SO post.

Also I found other resources on web majority of which were based on Pure CSS. Most of the answers in this post too are based on Pure CSS.

As a non-CSS developer the Pure CSS solutions, involving pseudo elements, I have found them to be lengthy and puzzling too. Puzzling because I could not figure out how the solution worked, by inspecting styling into the Developer's Tool on browsers.

Thus I preferred JS-based solution and @agconti's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517110/936494 helped in deriving it. Below I am posting my working solution

**Environment**

- Bootstrap 3.x
- jQuery 1.12.4
- Font Awesome Icons

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 square-radios-container">
            <div>
                <div class="square-radio">
                    <div class="square-radio-content"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></div>
                </div>
                <span class="square-radio-label">Option 1</span></div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <div class="square-radio">
                    <div class="square-radio-content"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></div>
                </div>
                <span class="square-radio-label">Option 2</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .square-radio {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    float: left;

    .square-radio-content {
      display: none;
      margin-top: -8px;
      margin-left: -2px;
      color: #00CDFF;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }

  .square-radio-label {
    margin-left: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

  bindClickEventOnSquareRadios = function() {
    var squareRadios = $('.square-radios-container').find('.square-radio');

    squareRadios.off('click').on('click', function(event) {
      var squareRadioObj = $(this);

      // Reset radio selection for all radios except the one clicked.
      var squareRadiosContainerObj = squareRadioObj.closest('.square-radios-container');
      var presentlyCheckedRadio = squareRadiosContainerObj.find('.square-radio-clicked').find('.square-radio-content').hide();
      presentlyCheckedRadio.find('.square-radio-content').hide();
      presentlyCheckedRadio.removeClass('square-radio-clicked');

      // Show the clicked radio as checked
      squareRadioObj.addClass('square-radio-clicked');
      squareRadioObj.find('.square-radio-content').show();
    });
  };

}) (jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    bindClickEventOnSquareRadios();
});
```

The rendered output looks like

[image]

Hope this helps someone who prefer JS-based solution for the requirement.

*Note: The styling should need to be tweaked to match the desired preference.*