# Create a radiobutton custom with kendo(change background-color)

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I would like to create a radio button with backgroundcolor=red.

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" id="car" name="carname" class="k-radio"/>
    <label class="k-radio-label" for="car">car</label>
```

I would to set background-color of kendo-radiobutton.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What have you tried? What problems did you have?

Comment: I wrote: style="background-color: red", but it doesn't work

Comment: You can't really change the appearance of radio buttons that much, you need to style the label instead. Here's an example of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516958/styling-radio-buttons-into-a-square/24517881#24517881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
input[type=radio].k-radio + .k-radio-label:before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Demo here](http://dojo.telerik.com/oBitU)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above changes the entire unfilled radio bubble color for KendoRadioButtons. If you want to change the color of the inside circle on checked items here's what I'm using:

```
input.k-radio:checked + label:after {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```