# Label for radio button styling

Tags: html, css

i have some radio buttons and their according labels:

```
<form ...>
  <label for="qty_1" class="lbl_quantity">1</label>
  <label for="qty_2" class="lbl_quantity">2</label>
  <label for="qty_3" class="lbl_quantity">3</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty_2" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty_3" value="3">
</form>
```

So what do i want ro achieve:

I want to pre-define three radio buttons for different quantities the user can select. I want those radio buttons to look like normal square buttons, so i thougt of using a label plus a hidden input.
Can someone help me to style these labels like normal buttons with a marked background when clicked, or, if possible style the radio buttons theirselves like square buttons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling radio buttons into a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516958/styling-radio-buttons-into-a-square)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check icheck jquery plugin for custom checkbox and radio buttons.

Check more at below link:-

http://git.io/arlzeA

But please remember you need to use inbuilt custom functions for check and uncheck.

```
$('.skin-flat input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
});
```

Just wrap text inside .skin-flat and Radio/checkbox class.

You can check more on this on below link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=icheck

Enjoy this is too nice :)

If you are using bootstrap then use below link:-

https://bootsnipp.com/tags/checkbox

Comment: thanks for the hint, but i want do it only by html and css